# Grabbing the title in plugin for ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, data-visualization, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I want to figure out how to grab the title in a plugin in ChartJS I have the title in the configuration like so:

```
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        fontSize: 10,                     
                        text: "This is my title",
                        padding: titlePadding,         
                    }
```

I was just curious if I want to do some afterDraw work, how do I grab it and alter it? I want to do some manipulation later in the event sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title text by calling `chart.titleBlock.options.text`, although even if you update it and call `chart.update()` it will render the updated title in the first draw tick but the other draw ticks it will use the normal defined title again, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/kc8qua61/12/

You are better off using a scriptable option for the title as shown in de documentation sample of chart.js here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/line/stepped.html.

It takes a part of the config to show in the title as a dynamic part and internally chart.js handles it, you can also use external variables here.